# Running rake commands in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am using cloudfoundry to deploy a rails 3.1 app. Is there a way to run common rake commands, like for e.g. rake db:reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also push another instance of the application, purposefully setting the application type to 'Standalone' and also bound to the same services. You will be then prompted for a command to run which you can set to something like;

```
bundle exec rake VERBOSE=true QUEUE=default resque:work
```

This example starts a Resque worker but you could easily start a different task.

Comment: You might also use `rails console` support: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/02/08/cloud-foundry-now-supports-the-rails-console/

Comment: Running rails console is useful. I could not find that easily in their documentation..either in the getting started guide or deploying a rails app guide. It would be helpful if those docs are updated along with the blog. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar question on their forums: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20160007-anyway-to-run-rake-db-seed-for-rails-app